# 2 Div's One Hidden and Appear on hover of 2nd

Tags: html, css, hover, jquery-hover

I have 2 divs next to each other, lets call them div A and div B

I want Div B hidden and when you hover over div a, div b appears, and then disappears when you are no longer hover hovering it.... Not sure what to put.

Comment: Post your HTML. You probably won't be able to do this if B isn't a child of A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With HTML like this:

```
<div class="a">
   This is div a.
</div>
<div class="b">
   This is div b.
</div>
```

You could use CSS like this:

```
.b {
  display:none;
}
.a:hover + .b {
  display:block;
}
```

So the B div starts off hidden with `display:none`, but when you hover over the A div, it becomes visible with `display:block`.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vj5tQ/)

Note: If the divs aren't directly adjacent to each other in the DOM, you would need to replace the `+` with a `~` to get the same effect.

Comment: Can't get much better than this! +1

Comment: I am having a issue now where when it appears it pushes the content around it. How do I position it so it appears next to the div but is fixed over the content so it does not move the other text/images or divs?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but you could use `position:absolute` if you need it to be in a specific position, and that won't have any effect on the surrounding elements.

Answer (score 1):

If the elements *aren't* siblings (or parent-child), you can't use pure CSS.  Since you included a jQuery(ish) tag, you could do this:

```
$('#a').on('mouseover', function() { $('#b').show(); });
$('#a').on('mouseout', function() { $('#b').hide(); });
```

See http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/gHetq for a working example.

Comment: The elements don't have to be directly adjacent. You can use the general sibling combinator (`~`) to reference an element that is further away.

Comment: Edited to reference siblings instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS alone, as the other answer suggests.

But if you want to do more during this hiding and showing (e.g. fading animations, sliding animation, or other jQuery stuff), then this is how it can be done with jQuery:

```
$('#a').hover( 
    function() { $('#b').fadeIn() },
    function() { $('#b').fadeOut() }    
);
```

jQuery's [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) has a variant that accepts two handlers - one for show, and the second for hide.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QPqzJ/)

Comment: Actually, thanks to transitions, you can achieve most of that sort of thing with pure CSS these days too. It just won't work on older versions of IE.